# Link Image Texture Path to Object Name

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I have a material node setup in cycles that I am trying to get an image texture file path to automatically updated based on the name of the object that the material is applied to. For example, if the object name is 123456 the image texture path should update to /Image-Textures/123456.png in the root folder of the .blend location.

Otherwise I am having to make a new material for every object since each has a different image texture. I think there should be a way to do this with python but my skills in that department are rather lacking.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104446/how-to-show-different-images-based-on-object-id

Comment: So I tried using OSL and after messing with it for a couple hours I realized it only works with CPU rendering which isnt really feasible for me. Is there any way around this?