# Animating Image Texture Change in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing, shaders, keyframes

I have a cube scene for the sake of example, but in my production, I use textures for the facial expressions of my character. The problem is, I don't know of an efficient way to animate the changing of a texture.

[image: example scene]

Blender insists that I cannot keyframe the changing of an image.

[image: "name" property cannot be animated]

Previously I have been naming all my files sequentially and animating the sequence, but that is severely impractical. Is there a better way to animate the changing of textures in cycles?

Thanks!

Comment: If OSL is an option (it does mean you can’t use GPU rendering) then this answer may be of use : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/104474/29586

Comment: Read this related link: [How do you animate image texture materials in blender cycles with keyframes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36748/how-do-you-animate-image-texture-materials-in-blender-cycles-with-keyframes/36793#36793)