# Image texture --- use every Nth image

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I have a series of images imported as an image texture. Is it possible to:

1. Use every Nth image?
2. Use each image or N rendered frames?

The first option results in a render using fewer frames than my image stack. The second creates a longer render by holding on images for more than one frames.

The specific goal is to do this before the compositor... applying these controls to image textures as they are applied to a material.

Comment: If OSL is an option (so you would lose the ability to render on GPu) then this answer provides a solution : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/104474/29586. You could then use the current frame with Maths nodes to control the image however you desire.

Comment: Thanks and very interesting, but not an optiopn on this job -- but something to consider and really cool.