# Offset UV of Sprite Sheet per instance on axis

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

Let say I have a Sprite Sheet 8 x 4 frames ... and I have a Plane arrayed by Geometry Nodes (imagine stock of layers on top of each other). So I would like to store one sprite sheet's frame per instance. I'm not looking for animation.

How can I offset UV (or sprite sheet) to fit sprite frames per instance?

I'm asking for solution with Sprite Sheet, because if I'm right - GN can't handle Image Sequence yet.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264619/

Comment: @quellenform ... not only related, but actually that is almost what I was tried to ask  for (in my bad way) - set UV under GN :) Sadly GN doesn't work with UDIMs (from what I tried), but I got it work for Sprite Sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UDIMs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/workflows/udims.html) to do it. UDIM tiles are 1x1 unit UV squares that can hold separate individual images in each tile. Starting from the bottom left, they can have up to 10 tiles horizontally, after that a second row is added, then a third, and so on. Adding $[1,0,0]$ to your texture's `Mapping`—*Location* would move your UV map one tile to the right horizontally (*u*). To reach the upper tiles, you add to the Y (*v*) axis.

First, have an image sequence named in the form of *filename.1001.jpg*, *filename.1002.jpg*, and so on...

[image]

Although you can generate the planes and set their UVs entirely inside *Geometry Nodes* procedurally, for simplicity's sake I'm gonna assume you'll unwrap and use a mesh plane as your input object to instance. In the setup below I simply array five planes/pages on a mesh line, and capture their indices as a named attribute.

In the *Shader Editor* you open your sprites as an image sequence by selecting them all after clicking *Open*. From the naming convention, Blender will automatically detect that they are UDIMs and switch to the appropriate mode. Using an `Attribute` node set to *Instancer*, we can now use the indices we stored beforehand to move the UV mapping sequentially, per instance:

[image]

For more than 10 images you need to add $1$ to your *Y* value after every 10th *X*, so you can switch to the upper row. Something like this should work:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for nice hint of UDIM :) I have two things - first I can't get it work - if you can check [my file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vJX337E1/) all stores number one ... Secondly - I explained it in a very bad way - I'm looking for a way to be able manipulate image inside GN as factor for [curve generation](https://blend-exchange.com/b/9Z4dsdyl/)

Comment: Make it probably more clear - I wanted to [answer this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279743) ... in a way to generate curve circle profiles based on image sequence and merge by loft node group. Since Texture node inside GN seems to be limited I'm not sure if this node can handle UDIM's kind of texture.

Comment: @vklidu Oh wow, I did not get your question's meaning _at all_. I'll try to find some time to think about that problem later if I can, but the UDIM problem is relatively easier. You need to reset your X value, and add 1 to your Y after every 10th X so you can switch to the upper row. Something like this would do it: https://i.imgur.com/H3YgBAS.png

Comment: OK thanks :) ... about UDIM's - I'm still missing something ... May I ask what was wrong with my file? And I don't mean 10+ ... My cards are still number 1. Hm

Comment: When I download your file, they're not all 1s, they go up to 10, but then cut out (don't go up to 20 like they should). Here: https://i.imgur.com/4uxRXCC.png Maybe you're using an old version of Blender and something has changed? (Or maybe you're looking at it in Solid—Texture mode and not with Eevee, somehow? https://i.imgur.com/TtVdF2g.png ) That question seems to have been deleted, btw.

Comment: At home. I worked in 3.4 Material mode ... now at work 3.5 it works ... hm OK thanks :) Ad - Deleted Q - Yeap :)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but this question has been answered before: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264619/ ...is this a duplicate?

Comment: Sure, they're both explaining how to use UDIMs for slightly different scenarios.

Comment: @quellenform Thanks to both of you ... I marked the Q as dupli ...