# Generate Points in a Color Center

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm looking for a way to generate a point at centre of each color in each layer.

[image]

Originaly I did a selection of faces per layer and used *Merge by Distance* node (that worked perfectly for layers with bigger distance between them, but of course it failed when layers became closer).

So I was thinking if there is a way to limit merge in X, Y axis (and ignore Z) ... here is an example of one separated "color" (red) per layer and I need single point at centre of this color (marked by pink points).

[image]

... or I'm open any efficient way to generate points at centre of each color directly from image texture if possible :)

Thanks

---

**Edit:** For now I'm using "workaround" - **increase layers distance / merge by distance / decrease layers distance back** ... that works here as suppose to ...

[image]
[image]

... but I'm still interested if there is a better way to detect centre points. Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: why don't you seperate your layers, use your method and move them then back? ;)

Comment: @Chris I'm probably tired ... how? (just consider there can be like hundreds layers) ... Thank you :)

Comment: animation nodes, python...? maybe even GN?

Comment: Purely GN ... from object generated like this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264619/ just instead of UDIM I use Sprite Sheet ... I can change layers distance, use merge, and change distance back after that ... It just sounds to me as workaround, than propper way ... But yes I will use it if no one here since I will need just a single node for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Accumulate Field node can do the job. You can use it to get the average position per layer, identical to the results from the workaround. Replace the Transform > Merge > Transform with nodes in the image.

[image: CenterPointGeoNodes]

[image]

Comment: Thanks works great :) I will try to learn how-why :)