# Multiple instances of a single image node, each with a different vector input

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, uv, node-editor, image

I need to use an image node for multiple different color inputs, but each with a different UV vector assigned to it.

This issue is quite hard for me to explain, so here's a drawing of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use MixRGB (not Mix Shader!), plug different vectors to it and use Factor (image or other nodes) to separate them. One output should go to input of single Image Texture. But what is the problem with simple duplicating of image texture node. Performance consideration? But I guess it will not affect render that much, if you are using same texture many times.

Comment: @SergeL I'm not quite sure what you mean... I need a node that can let me apply a vector to some RGB/image input. MixRGB doesn't have a vector input.

Comment: As for why I don't just use multiple image nodes; it's because I'm building a master node group that I will be using (potentially hundreds of times) as the basis for a project I'm making, and part of that group needs to re-use an image input multiple times (with different mappings each time). Plugging in the same input 4-5 times for many channels and many different material instances would be a HUGE inconvenience.
TL:DR for usability reasons. :)

Comment: Vector and RGB channels are basically the same. You can simply create two different UV maps, plug them into MixRGB and slide Factor from 1 to 0 to see that it switches well.

Comment: An Image Texture node can only produce a single output for any input vector - to get multiple simultaneous outputs you’ll need multiple image texture nodes. However, if the issue is that you need an easy way to change multiple inage texture nodes to the same image (so you only need to change the image in one place) - and you don’t mind using OSL - then perhaps this may help https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/104844/29586, a substitute Image Texture node that can be controlled by a String input that is generated from another OSL node.

Answer (score 2):

Both objects share same material and have UV map, but only Cube uses it due to different Vectors plugged into *MixRGB* node. Separation mask based on *Object Info* data and plugged into *Factor* of *MixRGB*.

[image]